# Regex search the 2 nearest keywords

Tags: regex

I want to search keyword `TIMESTAMP` in `CREATE TABLE`. This is my regex:

```
(?i)(\s+|^)CREATE\s+TABLE\s+\[\s*\bdbo\b\s*\]\.\[\w+\]\s*\(\s*((.|\n)*)\bTIMESTAMP
```

But it search CREATE TABLE in a query and TIMESTAMP in another query.

[Like this](https://regex101.com/r/Tic5LS/1)

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Please edit your question and show clear sample input data (both positive and negative cases), and also tell us what the expected output is.

Comment: Does `GO` appear on a line by itself after every SQL statement in your input text? (In your regex101 example it appears after the first statement but not after the second -- I don't know if you left it out when pasting in the second statement).

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement a parser using regex. That's wrong. Use a parser. They are two different things, and regex cannot be used alone to write a proper parser (though a regex lexer might be a useful component of a parser).

Answer (score 0):

When you just want to search Create Table and Timestamp you can use this simple regex:

```
(?i)(CREATE TABLE|TIMESTAMP)
```

The (?i) optional for case insensive.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, I think. OP appears to be looking for whether the value `timestamp` appears _within_ a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Then i understand it wrong. I think the he have to describe a bit more what he want to achieve.

Comment: If you look at the regex101 example OP provided becomes a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?im)^CREATE\s+TABLE\s+\[\s*dbo\s*\]\.\[\w+\]\s*\(\s*(.*(?:\n(?!CREATE\s+TABLE\b).*)*)\bTIMESTAMP\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JExx8r/1)

If your regex can't match a CR char with `.` add `\r?` before `\n`.

Note you do not need `\b` word boundaries on both ends of `dbo` as it is inside `[...]`.

**Details**

- `(?im)` - ignore case and multiline modes on
- `^` - start of a line
- `CREATE\s+TABLE\s+\[` - `CREATE TABLE [` with any 1+ whitespaces in between words
- `\s*dbo\s*` - a `dbo` string enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `\]\.\[` - `].[` string
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\]` - `]` char
  -`\s*\(\s*` - a `(` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*(?:\n(?!CREATE\s+TABLE\b).*)*)` - Group 1:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
  - `(?:\n(?!CREATE\s+TABLE\b).*)*` - 0 or more sequences of

    - `\n(?!CREATE\s+TABLE\b)` - a newline not followed with `CREATE TABLE`
    - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `\bTIMESTAMP\b` - a whole word `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to do it in two steps.

Step 1: find "complete" `CREATE TABLE` statements. Actually, find the span of the outermost parentheses.

```
(?i)(^ *)CREATE\s+TABLE\s+[^()]*\(([^()]*\([^()]*\))*[^()]*\)
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/ynCmJ4/1).

Step 2: find `timestamp` in the resulting found strings.